# Pipe list of files into program

Tags: windows, batch-file, xargs

I have a list of files to convert like this

```
C:\Users\jtl999\foo_001.jpg
C:\Users\jtl999\foo_002.jpg
```

To convert them manually I invoke the converter like this

```
convert_files.bat C:\Users\jtl999\foo_001.jpg
```

Basically what I want to do is read through the list of files one at a time and pass the file as a argument. On Linux I could use find and xargs but I am on Windows 7.

Comment: This list is in a text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for %f in ("c:\users\jtl999\foo_*.jpg") do call convert_files.bat "%~ff"
```

For each file in the indicated set, call the batch file, passing as a parameter the full path to the file

The syntax is for usage from command line. To use this in a batch file: Change the parameters of for command so that the percent sign is doubled. `%f` should be `%%f` and `%~f` should be `%%~f`

Comment: Just does what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %i in ('dir /b /s "C:\Users\jtl999\foo_*.jpg"') do call convert_files.bat "%i"
```

use `%%i` instead of `%i` in batch-files.

You need the parameter `/s` to get the full path. Although this means, you will also get any files in sub directories that fits your filter (if there are some).